# jQuery Animate Border Doesn't seems to work

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

The jQuery Animate border doesn't seems to work well in this code:
http://jsbin.com/ewuyup/13/edit

Does anyone have any idea to fix it?

I saw this on the jQuery site for Animate.

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. font, background, border) are not fully supported. For example, if you want to animate the rendered border width, at least a border style and border width other than "auto" must be set in advance. Or, if you want to animate font size, you would use fontSize or the CSS equivalent 'font-size' rather than simply 'font'.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to do it: set the border style and color in the css and put `borderWidth:"2px",` in your animate as such:

http://jsbin.com/ewuyup/20/

Answer (score 2):

You can't animate color and style for the border (there are however plugins for animating color), so you would set a zero width and the right style and color first, then animate the width using `"border-width"` instead of `"border"`:

Example:

```
$(".message_box_red").css({
  "border": "0px solid blue"
}).animate({
  "border-width":"5px",
  "margin":"1px",
  "padding":"7px",
  "width":" 409px",
  "height":"20px"
},2000,function()
```